# VB.Net Convert text to WWW form

Tags: vb.net, encoding, utf-8, httpwebrequest

I want to convert text into the WWW form.

E.g: `@` should be `%40`, `%` should be `%25` etc...

There's fine encoder [here](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), but i want to do it in VB.Net.

*I need this for httpwebrequest, i think it has something to do with **x-www-form-urlencoded**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`Uri.EscapeDataString()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx) for that:

```
Dim OriginalURL As String = "http://www.example.com/some file with spaces.php?q1=plus+&q2=at@&q3=svenska språkets 'ö'"
Dim EncodedURL As String = Uri.EscapeDataString(OriginalURL)
```

**Online test:** https://ideone.com/h5fqm1

And if you want to just escape parts of the URL but still keep valid components such as `: / = ? &` (etc.) you'd use [**`Uri.EscapeUriString()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Nice, yet i came up with my answer which is `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(my_string)`, but yours can help too, thanks!

Comment: @StefanĐorđević : Glad you found your own solution, but you should actually rather use `Uri.EscapeDataString()` to have compatibility with the [**RFC3986**](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1) standard. `HttpUtility.UrlEncode/-Decode` won't for instance escape spaces correctly as it turns them into `+` instead of `%20`.